# non removable notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notification-bar

In my app, there is service running on background. I want to notify user that the service is running. But I need that user cannot delete the notification - by pressing clear button or by swipe it out, in notification bar

[image]

It means I need to show my notification above Notification area

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is possible but the way you implement it depends on the API level you develop for.

For API levels below 11, you can set [Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR). This can be implemented like this:

```
// Create notification
Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.your_icon, "Example notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

// Set notification message
note.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Some text", "Some more text", clickIntent);

// THIS LINE IS THE IMPORTANT ONE            
// This notification will not be cleared by swiping or by pressing "Clear all"
note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

For API levels above 11, or when using the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html), one can implement it like this:

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
    .setContentTitle("Notification title")
    .setContentText("Notification content")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yourIcon)
    .setLargeIcon(R.drawable.yourBigIcon)
    .setOngoing(true) // Again, THIS is the important line
    .build();
```

Comment: In combitation with antew's post, I was exactly looking for Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT. Thanks a lot

Comment: can you try this android 8.1.0  is it working seems its not work ing

Answer (score 13):

To Create Non removable notification just use **setOngoing (true);**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                         new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_launcher)

                        .setContentTitle("My title")

                        .setOngoing(true)  

                        .setContentText("Small text with details");
```

Answer (score 3):

Sound like [Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR) or [Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To Create Non removable notification just use setOngoing (true);

To Create  removable notification just use setOngoing (false);