# Android Notification Old Way vs New Way

Tags: android

I've been trying to add notifications for my android app and I came across [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427204/non-removable-notification), which shows two ways to create a non clearable notification for different API levels.

I have used the older API style for creating the notification in my app and it works perfectly well but I was wondering if there are any issues with the older way or what benefits the newer API form offers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) approach provides a backward compatible API for supporting all API 4+ devices.

If you want to use [big view styles](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html) (available on Android 4.1+ devices), this allows you to add those features automatically on Android 4.1+ devices without writing if checks around the API version.

It is also the **only** way of [adding Wearable features to your notifications](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/index.html), including [voice input](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/voice-input.html), [additional pages](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/pages.html) of information, or [stacking](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html) notifications to provide additional information on wearables even when the phone is only showing a summary notification (using an `InboxStyle` for example).

Comment: Ah right, i didn't even think of the big view notifications or wearables. I thought the NotificationCompat only worked with newer APIs so i thought the older style might have  been beneficial for supporting older devices but as you said that isn't the case. Thanks a lot for you're help, I guess I'm better changing my code.

Comment: Yeah there's really no reason not to use the `NotificationCompat` classes rather than the built in defaults - any new APIs added to Android are also added to `NotificationCompat` as well which makes it much easier to support all API levels.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the best way to go. Thanks again.