# Android identifying what is on the upper part of the android notification bar

Tags: android

Currently I want to make an app but I don't know what this is called , I mean the android term for it, it's definately not a spinner, but more into the notifications.

I want to make an app that I can interact with just like the music bar here that can play music, stop next song , etc.

Can someone help me or tell me what that method is and where can I get some tutorials for it?

[image]

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427204/non-removable-notification

Comment: And maybe this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443946/music-player-control-in-notification

Comment: Sounds like Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR  which is user can not clear notification.This is custom view probably which added by remote views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be an ongoing notification. (It's not being under the Ongoing tag being the clue, otherwise I could be sure that this was the case)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29

It is probably a custom remote view

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html

A quick google search will give you examples.